# Dirac Delta function in the form of rectangular function

Tags: functions, signal-processing, dirac-delta

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONxWV.jpg)

The dirac function is an impulse and defined on a point. i am not able to understand the equivalence of the functions in the image . Explaining why they are equal would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather say that the dirac "function" is *not* definied on the one point we are most interested in

Comment: Is it actually possible to define the dirac delta as a regular function with domain $\mathbb{R}$? What is the codomain, then,  the infinitesimals?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yeah thats a more clear way to define it. the image attached which is giving me trouble. Sorry the main question is in the image ,i cant understand how both of them are equal

Comment: There's no assertion that the two are equal.  Rather this is saying  $\delta(x)$ is the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ of the second expression.  For every $\epsilon>0$, the integral of this function is one, the peak height gets smaller as $\epsilon$ gets smaller, and the width of the peak gets smaller as $\epsilon$ gets smaller.  This is a common intuitive explanation of the dirac delta, but a more rigorous explanation requires either generalized functions or distribution theory.

Comment: I think this question could be salvaged if the OP was a bit more clear and the material from the image was entered in MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the Dirac delta pulse is a thin (width zero) and high (height infinity) pulse with integral equal to one.

$\Pi$ is a not so thin (width one) and not so high (height one) pulse with integral equal to one. When you modify it as $\frac{1}{\epsilon} \Pi(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ you get a thinner and higher pulse, with width $\epsilon$ and height $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and still integral equal to one.

As $\epsilon \to 0$ this pulse gets even thinner and higher, and in this way gets closer to being a Dirac pulse.